# Histograms in Opencv

Tags: matlab, image-processing, opencv, histogram

I am trying to implement this particular command in MATLAB to opencv.I am working in Linux Ubuntu.Can you help me figure out the code in opencv for this.

out_vector=hist(G_vector,0:17:255);
G_vector is an array of size 1X100 which represents 1 component of an image.

I am using the following code

```
vector<Mat> rgb_planes;
       split(image,rgb_planes);
       int histSize = 255;

         /// Set the ranges ( for R,G,B) )
         float range[] = { 0,17, 255 } ;
         const float* histRange = { range };

         bool uniform = true; bool accumulate = false;

         Mat r_hist, g_hist, b_hist,g_hist1;

         /// Compute the histograms:
         calcHist( &rgb_planes[0], 1, 0, Mat(), r_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
         calcHist( &rgb_planes[1], 1, 0, Mat(), g_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
         calcHist( &rgb_planes[2], 1, 0, Mat(), b_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );

         // Draw the histograms for R, G and B
         int hist_w = 400; int hist_h = 400;
         int bin_w = cvRound( (double) hist_w/histSize );

         Mat histImage( hist_w, hist_h, CV_8UC3, Scalar( 0,0,0) );

         /// Normalize the result to [ 0, histImage.rows ]
         normalize(r_hist, r_hist, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );
         normalize(g_hist, g_hist, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );
         normalize(b_hist, b_hist, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );
```

Can you suggest where should I make changes here

Comment: No reply in 2 hours.Please help me out here guys

Comment: why do you want to change it? what went wrong? One thing I can suggest is that `0:17:255` means that your `range[]` should be `{0,17,34,51,...}` (ie add 17 until you get up to 255).

Answer (score 2):

`histSize` controls the number of bins in each dimension. If you want 16 bins in those one dimensional histograms, use:

```
int histSize[] = { 16 };
```

or I guess just int histSize = 16; would work.

Set the bin boundaries to be from 0 to 255  like this:

```
  float intensity_range = { 0, 256 }; //upper bound is exclusive
  const float * histRange[] = { intensity_range };
```

OpenCV's calcHist provides a configurability that few people will ever need. [Check out the method description and example code here](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=histogram#void%20cvCalcHist%28IplImage%2a%2a%20image,%20CvHistogram%2a%20hist,%20int%20accumulate,%20const%20CvArr%2a%20mask%29).

Comment: The code does compile.But I want to quantize the values in the histogram to 16 bins.

Comment: what ut_vector=hist(G_vector,0:17:255) does is basically counts the number of pixel values which belong to a certain bin.for example if the values are [15 20 30 45] then 15 falls in 0-15 bin,20 in 16-31 and so on